# Copy file from 'root' to 'user' gives a broken link

Tags: nautilus, 23.04

So. I'd like to copy one of my Java folders to my user to then copy to somewhere else (don't ask why).
However, whenever I do it, even with sudo, I get a 'Broken Link' that does nothing.
I've tried these things:
Using terminal normally.
Using nautilus normally.
Using sudo and terminal.
Using sudo and nautilus.

But **every single time** I try, it just makes me a broken link.
See here:
[image: sudo cp java-1.8(etc) /home/xendyex/Desktop/files/myjavastuff java and an empty folder.]
or... (white app is sudo, dark is not)
[image: photo of sudo nautilus and normal nautilus with a broken link in the normal window]
This is probably a stupid question, but... any help? Thanks.
I'm using 23.04

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jul 20 10:09 java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-17-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug  3 11:54 java-17-openjdk-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 Jul 24 21:17 java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-8-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug  5 18:01 java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

I'm trying to replace a Java version for Minecraft.

Comment: Did you ever try adding the -r (recusion) to the copy as the error message notes?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve with this copying. Copy&paste the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm` to your question *as text*. The file you are copying is probably a symbolic link to a subdirectory next to it, and if you copy only the link, then the copied link will be broken. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

As the output of `ls -l` indicates, `java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` is not a real subdirectory, but a **symbolic link** to subdirectory `java-8-openjdk-amd64` located **in the same directory** (`/usr/lib/jvm` in this case). Which is btw. also indicated by the arrow sign next to the folder icon in Nautilus - the arrow sign indicates it's a link.

So if you copy that link to another location, and don't copy the corresponding subdirectory `java-8-openjdk-amd64` to the same location as well, the copied link will be broken, as the object it points to does not exist.

This happens because the link points to a **relative** name, which is resolved using the same base directory as the directory that contains the link. If the link would point to an absolute name like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64` instead of just `java-8-openjdk-amd64`, it could be copied to any location without becoming broken.

You can create such link yourself, without the need to copy the original one. Go to your target directory:

```
cd /home/xendyex/Desktop/files/myjavastuff
```

and type the command:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

You have created a link `java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` in your directory `/home/xendyex/Desktop/files/myjavastuff` that points to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`.

But note this **does not copy** the original Java folder (if this is what you wanted to do), it only creates a **link** to it in another location. If you want to make an actual copy, you need to copy the actual subdirectory `java-8-openjdk-amd64` and not the link.